# Variation of the induced metric

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, string-theory, metric-tensor, variational-calculus

Nambu-Goto action

$$
S=-\mu\int\gamma^{1/2}d^2\xi
$$
where $\gamma_{AB}=g_{\mu\nu}X^{\mu},_A X^{\nu},_B$
.
Euler-Lagrange equations:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi^A} \left(\frac{\partial\gamma^{1/2}}{\partial X^{\mu},_A}\right)-\frac{\partial\gamma^{1/2}}{\partial X^{\mu}}=0
$$

The variation of $\gamma^{1/2}$:
$$
\delta\gamma^{1/2}=\frac{1}{2}\gamma^{1/2}\gamma^{AB}\delta\gamma_{AB}
$$
My question is how to variate the induced metric $\gamma_{AB}$? I guess it should be variated with respect to spacetime coordinates and and spacetime metric. 
$$
\delta\gamma_{AB}=\delta(g_{\mu\nu})X^{\mu},_A X^{\nu},_B+2g_{\mu\nu}\delta(X^{\mu},_A) X^{\nu},_B
$$
And the second question is, if the variation is true, then, when the derivative of $\gamma_{AB}$ with respect to $X^{\mu},_A$ and $X^{\mu}$ is evaluated must be $\delta g_{\mu\nu}=0$ and $\delta(X^{\mu},_A)=0$, similarly to the derivative of multivariable function?

Comment: I have a problem with differentiation of $\gamma^{1/2}$ wrt. $X^{\mu}_A$ and $X^{\mu}$.

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3516884/11127

Answer (score 1):

OP is essentially asking how the [Nambu-Goto (NG) action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nambu%E2%80%93Goto_action) principle works. We should stress that there is no variation wrt. to the target space metric $g_{\mu\nu}(X)$ per se: It is treated as a background metric. The variation is purely wrt. the target space coordinates fields $X^{\mu}(\xi)$. It is straightforward exercise to derive the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for $X^{\mu}(\xi)$. For the Dirac-Bergmann constraint analysis of the NG action, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184301/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: I understood the Nambu-Goto action. The aim is to write the EOM in an explicit form evaluating the derivatives of Lagrangian density.

Comment: I am trying to bring to the following form to evaluate the derivatives. $\delta S(x,\dot{x})=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\delta x+\frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{x}}\delta \dot{x}$