# Variation of induced metric in Nambu-Goto action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, string-theory, variational-calculus

I'm working with the Nambu-Goto action
$$
S=-\mu\int d^2\zeta\sqrt{\gamma}
$$
with $\gamma$ the determinant of the pull-back metric
$$
\gamma_{ab}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{X}^2 & \dot{X}\cdot X' \\
\dot{X}\cdot X' & X'^2
\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{dX^{\mu}}{d\zeta^a}\frac{dX^{\nu}}{d\zeta^b}\eta_{\mu\nu}
$$
where dots and primes relate to differentiation with respect to the components of the parameterization of $\zeta=\zeta(\tau,\sigma).$ In [his string theory notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html), Tong suggests that there is a straightforward way to get the equations of motion of this system. Namely
$$
0=\delta S=-\mu\int d^2\zeta\delta\sqrt{-\gamma}
$$
makes Euler-Lagrange equations. We can exploit a well-known identity that
$$
\delta\sqrt{-\gamma}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-\gamma}\gamma^{ab}\delta\gamma_{ab}.
$$
Of course this must vanish via the principle of stationary action. Tong (and many others) gives the resulting Euler-Lagrange equation from this variation as
$$
\partial_{\alpha}(\sqrt{-\gamma}\gamma^{ab}\partial_{\beta}X^{\mu})=0.
$$
Obviously the variation of the pullback must be $2\partial_{\beta}X^{\mu}$, but aside from the factor of two (index manipulation) I'm not sure *why* this is the right answer. This question has been asked [before](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/526165/) without a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\gamma_{ab} = \partial_a X^\mu \partial_b X_\mu \implies \gamma^{ab} \delta \gamma_{ab}  = 2 \gamma^{ab} \partial_a X^\mu \partial_b \delta X_\mu.
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
\delta S &= - \frac{\mu}{2} \int d^2 \zeta  \sqrt{-\gamma}2 \gamma^{ab} \partial_a X^\mu \partial_b \delta X_\mu \\
&=  \mu \int d^2 \zeta \partial_b [ \sqrt{-\gamma} \gamma^{ab} \partial_a X^\mu ] \delta X_\mu + \text{bdy term}
\end{align}
The equation of motion is then
$$
 \partial_b [ \sqrt{-\gamma} \gamma^{ab} \partial_a X^\mu ] = 0 \implies \nabla^2 X^\mu = 0.
$$

---

### Variations

OP asked me to clarify how the variation of $\gamma$ was derived. Think of $\gamma_{ab}$ as a function of $X$,
$$
\gamma_{ab}(X) = \partial_a X^\mu \partial_b X_\mu
$$
Then, the variation is the simple statement
$$
\delta \gamma_{ab}(X) = \gamma_{ab} ( X + \delta X ) - \gamma_{ab} (X)
$$
where on the RHS, only the linear term in $\delta X$ is kept.

In our case, we have
\begin{align}
\delta \gamma_{ab}(X) &= \partial_a [ X^\mu + \delta X^\mu ] \partial_b [ X_\mu + \delta X^\mu ] - \partial_a X^\mu \partial_b X_\mu \\
&= \partial_a X^\mu \partial_b \delta X_\mu + \partial_a \delta X^\mu \partial_b X_\mu + O( (\delta X)^2 ) . 
\end{align}
It follows that
$$
\gamma^{ab} \delta \gamma_{ab}  = 2 \gamma^{ab} \partial_a X^\mu \partial_b \delta X_\mu
$$

Comment: In your second line you write an expression for $\gamma^{ab}\delta\gamma_{ab}$. How do you find $\delta\gamma_{ab}$?

Comment: I defined gamma in the first line. Then I just literally varied it. Do you know how to vary fields to derive equations of motion?

Comment: No, it's been a long time since I've seen this stuff. I'm not comfortable with it anymore. I guess I naïvely am assuming that since a variation is *like* a derivative that $\delta\gamma_{ab}$ should look something like $\delta g_{\mu\nu}\partial_aX^{\mu}\partial_bX^{\nu}+2g_{\mu\nu}\delta\partial_aX^{\mu}\partial_bX^{\nu}$ but even if that's correct, I'm not to sure where to go from there. It seems like we should get a nasty term with Christoffels in it from varying $g_{\mu\nu}$ with respect to $X$, but that isn't the case here.

Comment: OK, then you need to learn that first. No point in trying to study string theory without learning the basics.

Comment: ‍♂️I'm looking at a few treatments of the material, so of course there's nothing about $g_{\mu\nu}$ here - that's not how the pull-back is defined in Tong's notes. So $\delta\gamma_{ab}=2\eta_{\mu\nu}\delta(\frac{dX^{\mu}}{d\zeta^a})\frac{dX^{\nu}}{d\zeta^b}$. The variation of the derivative term is the limit as $\varepsilon\rightarrow0$ of $\frac{d(X^{\mu}+\varepsilon Y^{\mu})}{d\zeta^a}$. The second term vanishes in the limit of little $\varepsilon$ so the variation of $X^{\mu}_{,~a}$ is $X^{\mu}_{,~a}$. Is this on the right track here?

Comment: I will modify my answer to explain variations, but I seriously suggest you go back to absolute basics - QFT 101. Trust me, it'll be exceedingly difficult for you to follow anything if you do not first strengthen your fundamentals. Variations occur so often in physics that you need to be able to do it while asleep to continue onwards.

Comment: I appreciate the help. It's clear that there's a gap in my knowledge. I remember talking a lot about variations in the formulation of the Schwinger-Dyson equations - maybe I'll look back at those notes.